# How can I restrict who has access to the GraphiQL API browser with graphene-django?

Tags: permissions, graphene-python, graphene-django

Graphene-Django [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/installation/) note that you can pass `graphiql=False` when instantiating the `GraphQLView` if you do not want to use the GraphiQL API browser. However, I'd like to keep the GraphiQL API browser available, and merely restrict who has access to it. How can that be done?

For instance, how would I make it so that only "staff" users (who can access the Admin site) have permission to access the GraphiQL browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the Graphene-Django `GraphQLView` and override its `can_display_graphiql` method (defined [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/5dea6ffa41141d84c367ac1f90c0affafe0d9da4/graphene_django/views.py#L344-L347%C2%A0)) to add this sort of logic.

```py
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView as BaseGraphQLView

class GraphQLView(BaseGraphQLView):
    @classmethod
    def can_display_graphiql(cls, request, data):
        # Only allow staff users to access the GraphiQL interface
        if not request.user or not request.user.is_staff:
            return False
        return super().can_display_graphiql(request, data)
```

Then in your urls.py file, use your new `GraphQLView` instead of the default one:

```py
# import the GraphQLView defined above
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("graphql", GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True)),
]
```